# Settings screen layout style

Tags: android, layout

I am creating a new settings screen for my app and want to keep the look and feel similar to that of the standard applications.  I have seen many 3rd party apps also follow this style (Twidroid for example) and would like to know how best to go about creating this look?

Is there a "template" or Activity I can use or is it a case of constructing it from a table layout or similar?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [preference XML](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceScreen.html) and [`PreferenceActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) for settings to get the common look and feel. You can then access those settings via [`PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getDefaultSharedPreferences%28android.content.Context%29).

[Here are three sample projects](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Prefs/) that demonstrate various aspects of the preference XML format.